# Qt miss resources after deploying

Tags: qt, macdeployqt

I have simple Qt program. I have figured out how to use macdeployqt for deploying my app on macbooks without qt installed. But after installation from dmg (it is created using macdeployqt with -dmg option) no resources are displayed.

I added resources to project like this
[image]

It displays correctly if I simply put the app bundle from build to my program folder, but it is missing after deploying. What have I done wrong?

Comment: In principle resources are converted by the `rcc` program in a C++ file and compiled into the main executable. Read http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html for more informations

Comment: I have added images directly into resources folder in app bundle and it works fine. But it seems absurdly. Why QtCreator does not add it during build app bundle?

Comment: Because resource files are already inside the compiled executable. You access them programmatically via e.g. `QSvgRenderer my_bad(":/images/bad.svg");`